# Subquery to pull sum amount from different table and group by salesperson

Tags: sql

--I am trying to simply add one subquery to take the total sales of each salesperson in relation to their quotes. I am at a loss and hopefully someone can help.

```
select sp.FIRST_NAME + ' ' + sp.LAST_NAME,
sum(case when sq.SAL_QUOTE_STATUS_ID = '1' then 1 else 0 end) as [Created],
sum(case when sq.SAL_QUOTE_STATUS_ID = '4' then 1 else 0 end) as [Ordered],
sum(case when sq.SAL_QUOTE_STATUS_ID = '3' then 1 else 0 end) as [Rejected],
sum(sq.AMOUNT_INCLUDING_TAX) as [Amount],
sum(sq.COST) as [Cost],
sum(sq.AMOUNT_INCLUDING_TAX - sq.COST) as [Profit],
round(100 * (case when sum(sq.AMOUNT_INCLUDING_TAX) > 0 then 
(sum(sq.AMOUNT_INCLUDING_TAX) -
    sum(sq.COST)) / sum(sq.AMOUNT_INCLUDING_TAX) else 0 end), 3) as [GP%],
    (Select sum(so.amount_including_tax)
     from SAL_SALES_ORDER so
     where so.SALESPERSON_ID = sp.SALESPERSON_ID) as [YTD Sales]
from SAL_SALES_QUOTE sq
inner join CRM_SALESPERSON sp on sp.SALESPERSON_ID = sq.SALESPERSON_ID
where sq.CREATED_DATE > '01-01-2018'
group by sp.FIRST_NAME + ' ' + sp.LAST_NAME
```

Comment: Can you point out where in your code you have an example of what you are looking for?

Comment: yes i am not following what the problem is either- if you want the overall total for each person just add the sum columns

Comment: What's your DBMS?Please provide some sample data.

Comment: Btw, hopefully you don't have two sales person with the same name, `John Smith` and `John Smith` :-)

Comment: This is invalid standard SQL. Which DBMS product are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took your subquery out of the select, made it into a result set to join on , and then pulled the sum from there.

```
select sp.FIRST_NAME + ' ' + sp.LAST_NAME,
sum(case when sq.SAL_QUOTE_STATUS_ID = '1' then 1 else 0 end) as [Created],
sum(case when sq.SAL_QUOTE_STATUS_ID = '4' then 1 else 0 end) as [Ordered],
sum(case when sq.SAL_QUOTE_STATUS_ID = '3' then 1 else 0 end) as [Rejected],
sum(sq.AMOUNT_INCLUDING_TAX) as [Amount],
sum(sq.COST) as [Cost],
sum(sq.AMOUNT_INCLUDING_TAX - sq.COST) as [Profit],
round(100 * (case when sum(sq.AMOUNT_INCLUDING_TAX) > 0 then 
(sum(sq.AMOUNT_INCLUDING_TAX) -
    sum(sq.COST)) / sum(sq.AMOUNT_INCLUDING_TAX) else 0 end), 3) as [GP%],
sum([x.ytd_sales]) AS YTD_Sales
from SAL_SALES_QUOTE sq
inner join CRM_SALESPERSON sp on sp.SALESPERSON_ID = sq.SALESPERSON_ID
inner join (Select so.salesperson_id, sum(so.amount_including_tax) AS [YTD Sales]
         from SAL_SALES_ORDER so
         group by so.salesperson_id) x
ON x.salesperson_id = sp.salesperson_id
where sq.CREATED_DATE > '01-01-2018'
group by sp.FIRST_NAME + ' ' + sp.LAST_NAME
```